# Pentaho Kettle/PDI fails on second request

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have the latest version of Kettle/PDI. Carte is running locally on Windows with the following configuration:

```
<slave_config>
  <slaveserver>
    <name>master1</name>
    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
    <port>8081</port>
    <master>Y</master>
  </slaveserver>
  <repository>
    <name>PDI Repo</name>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </repository>
</slave_config>
```

And in .kettle/repositories.xml:

```
<repositories>
  <connection>
    <name>PDI Repo</name>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server>
    <type>MYSQL</type>
    <access>Native</access>
    <database>pdi</database>
    <port>3306</port>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>Encrypted password</password>
    <servername/>
    <data_tablespace/>
    <index_tablespace/>
    <attributes>
      <attribute><code>EXTRA_OPTION_MYSQL.defaultFetchSize</code><attribute>500</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>EXTRA_OPTION_MYSQL.useCursorFetch</code><attribute>true</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>FORCE_IDENTIFIERS_TO_LOWERCASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>FORCE_IDENTIFIERS_TO_UPPERCASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>IS_CLUSTERED</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>PORT_NUMBER</code><attribute>3306</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>PRESERVE_RESERVED_WORD_CASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>QUOTE_ALL_FIELDS</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>STREAM_RESULTS</code><attribute>Y</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>SUPPORTS_BOOLEAN_DATA_TYPE</code><attribute>Y</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>SUPPORTS_TIMESTAMP_DATA_TYPE</code><attribute>Y</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>USE_POOLING</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
    </attributes>
  </connection>
  <repository>
    <id>KettleDatabaseRepository</id>
    <name>PDI Repo</name>
    <description>PDI Repo</description>
    <connection>PDI Repo</connection>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

You'll notice these are pretty much the default with some specific configuration for the repository database. Through Spoon, I've created a simple transformation that runs a select on a database table, performs some simple calculations on the columns, and returns some JSON.

If I tell the transformation to run on master1, it works and spits out the JSON.

If I run exactly the same command again, it errors:

```
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo - ERROR (version 6.0.1.0-386, build 1 from 2015-12-03 11.37.25 by buildguy) : Error disconnecting from database :
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo - Unable to commit repository connection
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo - Error comitting connection
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run (RunThread.java:121)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.BaseStep.markStop (BaseStep.java:2992)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans$1.stepFinished (Trans.java:1233)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.fireTransFinishedListeners (Trans.java:1478)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.www.BaseJobServlet$3.transFinished (BaseJobServlet.java:170)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.disconnect (KettleDatabaseRepository.java:1655)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.disconnect(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:257)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.commit(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:283)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.commit (Database.java:738)
2016/01/29 10:05:53 - PDI Repo -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.commit (Database.java:757)
```

I don't understand why the connection to the repository database fails after the first request. Carte continues to run, despite this error, but will throw errors like this when accessed via URL:

```
<webresult>
<result>ERROR</result>
<message>Unexpected error executing the transformation: 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:128)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:106)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2716)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2684)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2661)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2641)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2606)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2569)
    at org.pentaho.di.www.ExecuteTransServlet.loadTransformation(ExecuteTransServlet.java:316)
    at org.pentaho.di.www.ExecuteTransServlet.doGet(ExecuteTransServlet.java:232)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)</message>
<id />
</webresult>
```

I dug through the code for that stack trace, and that means the Repository object is `null`. So, for some reason, Carte can connect to the PDI repository, but when it succeeds once, something errors and it drops the connection and can no longer find the transformations.